# How to send mail without asking a sender account for permission?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, email, outlook

I'm trying to make a VB.NET app that sends a mail to a certain email account, that account's domain is not gmail,hotmail,etc. it belongs to the company where I work.
My problem is, Outlook prompts a warning that says "a program is attempting to send email on your behalf..." and it requires a click to send the mail(that's because it is using the current PC user account to send the mail). I need to make it automatized(no clicks required)

Since this is the first time I do this kind of thing, I must ask if there is a way to send the mail without a sender account? So I don't need to ask for permission to send the mail nor write any password in the code. Or if it is not possible at least a way to make my .exe "trusted" for any PC inside the company where it is executed.

What lines do I have to change in my code to skip that message?

```
 Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim date As String
        Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process    

        For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
            If proc.MainWindowTitle.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                proc.Kill()
            End If
        Next

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\file.xlsm")
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet")

        Try
            xlWorkSheet.Range("E4").Select()
            xlWorkSheet.Range("E4").Activate()
            date = xlApp.ActiveCell.Value

            Do While Convert.ToString(xlApp.ActiveCell.Value) <> ""
               'The mail part start here
                If (DateTime.Today - CDate(date)).Days = 180 Then
                    OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                    OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                    'On Error Resume Next
                    With OutMail
                        .To = "xxxx@xxxx.com" 
                        .CC = ""
                        .BCC = ""
                        .Subject = "subject"
                        .Body = "text"
                        .Send()
                    End With
                    ' On Error GoTo 0

                    OutMail = Nothing
                    OutApp = Nothing

                End If

                xlApp.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select()
                date = xlApp.ActiveCell.Value

            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.ToString())           

        End Try
```

This is a console app, so there is no `web.config` here.
Please help.

Comment: Try sending via SMTP instead of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try third party email service providers like Amazon SES, SendGrid, etc. Then using SMTP or APIs provided by them you can send mail from any email address but note that you need to authorize the email address just one time.

They generally send an email with a link to an email address and you just need to click on it to authorize that address.